# Convergence of credible regions on simple Bayesian model

Tags: bayesian, asymptotics, credible-interval

Consider a basic Bayesian model :
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
\theta &\sim &\pi(\theta)\\
X_1, \cdots, X_n&\overset{IID}{\sim} &\mathcal{N}(\theta, I_d)\\
\end{array}
$$
where $d$ is the (fixed) dimension of random variable $X$.

The posterior distribution is given by:
$$\pi(\theta\mid X)\propto \pi(\theta)\varphi\left(\sqrt{n}(\theta - \overline{X})\right) $$
where $\varphi$ is the density of a $d$-dimensional standard normal random variable.
Consider the highest density credible regions defined by $C_n = \{\theta : \pi(\theta\mid X) \geq h_n\}$ where $h_n$ insures a given coverage of $1 - \alpha$.

**Question** : Can we show that, when $n\to\infty$, $\sqrt{n}(C_n - \overline X)$ converges to the ellipsoïd of level $1-\alpha$ under standard normal distribution ? Under what assumptions on the prior distribution $\pi$?

I expect this to be true, since the prior influence would vanish asymptotically (suppose the prior has support equal to $\mathbb{R}^d$) but I cannot prove it. Maybe assuming the prior to be log-concave could help, since it guarantees the credible regions to be convex... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer needs some concepts of stochastic geometry such as a distance between random sets. What would help is a *log-concave* prior, because the likelihood is log-concave hence the HPD regions will then be convex. I suspect that the result is false for some nasty priors: mixture of Dirac distributions, heavy tail, ...

Comment: @Yves. Thanks. You are right, prior should be log concave, not convex. I edited it. 
For the distance between sets, I think Hausdorff distance would fit well here. 
Mixture of Dirac would certainly no work, but heavy-tailed distribution I'm not so sure: with an improper flat prior over $\mathbb{R}^d$, the property is true.

Comment: Yes a proper prior, even with heavy tail should not be worth than the flat improper prior.